# Filter object where queried number is within a range

Tags: django, django-queryset

Lets say I have a model with a `low` and a `high` forming a range, and want to find that instance if a number falls within that range.

| ID | Prefix | Low | High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | GH | 1 | 300 |
| 4 | GH | 450 | 700 |

If I were to search `GH250` then I should get back the instance with ID of `3` in this example.

I considered using `range()` to get a list of all the numbers within a range, but this would require me to query every instance with a prefix of `GH` first & then build a range for each & every one of them to find which one overlaps.

To limit this, I do at least have the `low` & `high` available, so I could query all instance with a prefix of `GH` where `high` is under `250` and that somewhat scales the results down, but this is still a pretty big query.

This is my current query which just looks for the `prefix` & the `low` or `high` containing the number.

```py
prefix = search[:2]
number = search[2:]

queryset = queryset.filter(
                        Q(Q(low__icontains=number) |
                        Q(high__icontains=number)) &
                        Q(prefix__icontains=prefix)
                    )
```

What tools might be available to me to efficiently filter results to get the block that contains the number I'm searching for?

Comment: High and low "containing the number" looks strange. If one queries for `GH200`, then should it return the item with id 3?

Comment: Correct, GH200 would be the range with ID of 3.

Comment: Every prefix length are same of each other?

Comment: Yes, prefixes are always 2 characters, but the main focus is handling a search of the inward range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
prefix = search[:2]
number = search[2:]

queryset = queryset.filter(
    prefix=prefix,
    low__lte=number,
    high__gte=number
)
```

You can boost efficiency by setting a [**`db_index=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on the `low` and `high` columns.